# Extract month from date with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to extract the month from a date formatted as a character. I first convert the strings in column 1 to a date format (class character). However, I am unable to extract the month.

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c(44008, 44001, NA, 77), col2=c(43476, 43479, 77, NA))
df
  col1  col2
1 44008 43476
2 44001 43479
3    NA    77
4    77    NA
```

My attempt

```
df %>%
# convert to date
mutate_at(vars(col1), funs(case_when((nchar(col1)>4)~(as.character(as.Date(as.numeric(col1), origin="1899-12-30"))), TRUE~as.character(col1))) ) %>% 
  mutate(
    # extract month
    col1_month = case_when(nchar(col1)==10~lubridate::month(col1), TRUE~as.character(col1)))
```

I've tried various tricks but can't seem to get this to work.

Desired output:

```
        col1  col2 col1_month
1 2020-06-26 43476          6
2 2020-06-19 43479          6
3       <NA>    77         NA
4         77    NA         77
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `col1_month` to equal `col1` for values with 4 or less digits? I would think NA is a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `case_when`, the 'type' should be the same across the output from all the conditions.  In the first case, we convert to 'Date' from the `numeric` column `across` the 'col' columns, then reconvert it to `character` class to avoid a clash with other values.  In the 'col1_month', the 'col1' is converted to `Date` again before extracting the `month`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('col'), 
    ~ case_when(nchar(.) > 4 ~ 
         as.character(as.Date(., origin = '1899-12-30')),
       TRUE ~ as.character(.))), 
   col1_month = case_when(nchar(col1) == 10 ~ 
            as.character(month(as.Date(col1))), TRUE ~ col1))
```

-output

```
#        col1       col2 col1_month
#1 2020-06-26 2019-01-11          6
#2 2020-06-19 2019-01-14          6
#3       <NA>         77       <NA>
#4         77       <NA>         77
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your logic and code is rather more complex than it needs to be. I'd just convert everything in `col1` to a date, store that in its own column and extract the months.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(col1, origin="1899-12-30"), 
         Month = month(Date))

   col1  col2       Date Month
1 44008 43476 2020-06-26     6
2 44001 43479 2020-06-19     6
3    NA    77       <NA>    NA
4    77    NA 1900-03-17     3
```

And then apply the logic to use dates in a certain range later on. For example:

```
df %>% 
  filter(nchar(col1) > 4) %>%
  # do stuff...
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` approach can be:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(col1=c(44008, 44001, NA, 77), col2=c(43476, 43479, 77, NA))
#Compute date
df$Date <- as.Date(df$col1, origin = "1899-12-30")
#Extract month
df$Month <- as.numeric(format(df$Date,'%m'))
#Format for filling
df$Date <- as.character(df$Date)
df$Date <- ifelse(nchar(df$col1)>4,df$Date,df$col1)
df$Month <- ifelse(nchar(df$col1)>4,df$Month,df$col1)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2       Date Month
1 44008 43476 2020-06-26     6
2 44001 43479 2020-06-19     6
3    NA    77       <NA>    NA
4    77    NA         77    77
```